# Add extensions to popular Android browsers?

Tags: browser, browser-add-ons

Is there any simple way to make extensions work on your Android phone with popular working browsers like Chrome or Microsoft Edge, or do you have to download other browsers for this to work out?

If there is a simple solution, does anyone know how to go forward with it?

Answer (score 2):

Kiwi Browser, a Chromium fork, supports Chrome extensions on Android.

Comment: I see, so the only simple way is to install a browser that has extension support?

Answer (score 1):

I guess Chrome and Edge for Android don't support extensions.
Firefox is a good choice, in my opinion

Comment: Firefox also has only a very limited list of available plugins for the Android version.

Comment: In general, yes, but it should be sufficient for the average user.